# How to show that the series $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} C6^j \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{j^2}<\infty?$

Tags: calculus, analysis

> How to show that the series 
>   $$ \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} C6^j \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{j^2}<\infty?$$

I feel like that $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{j^2}\to 0$ is faster than $6^j\to \infty$ as $j\to \infty$. Is it right?

Note:  here $C$ is a constant.

Comment: Well, it would seem to depend on $a_j$.

Comment: @lulu Sorry, I edit some constant but not $a_j$.

Comment: Then, yes, it converges.  To prove it, show some inequality like $2^{j^2}>6^{2j}$ for sufficiently large $j$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Series converges absolutely by Cauchy's radical test:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{6^n \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n^2}} = 6\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n} = 0 < 1$$